# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, jtable

The titled exception throwing in a table when I run a method where a row might be deleted there and after that when I try to clear the table rows. Can any one explain me why is this happening? I am not an expert in java.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:430)
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:632)
        at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2652)
        at classes.RowListener.displayRowValues(RowListener.java:40)
        at classes.RowListener.valueChanged(RowListener.java:32)
        at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:167)
        at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:147)
        at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:194)
        at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeIndexInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:660)
        at javax.swing.JTable.tableRowsDeleted(JTable.java:4460)
        at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4363)
        at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:280)
        at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(AbstractTableModel.java:245)
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setNumRows(DefaultTableModel.java:304)
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(DefaultTableModel.java:322)
        at saraentry.MainFace.clearTable(MainFace.java:73)
        at saraentry.MainFace.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainFace.java:578)
        at saraentry.MainFace.access$1200(MainFace.java:32)
        at saraentry.MainFace$14.actionPerformed(MainFace.java:424)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 20 seconds)
```

Code:

```
public class MainFace extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public String selectedRaw, tColSqNum, tColJobNo, tColDecName, tColDate;
String pendingDate, getTDate;

/** Creates new form MainFace */
public MainFace() {
    theme.theme();
    initComponents();
    newJob.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    tm.setRowCount(0);
    ListSelectionModel selectionModel = jTable1.getSelectionModel();
    selectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new RowListener(this));
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date Sysdate = new Date();
    lblDate.setText(dateFormat.format(Sysdate));
    jXDatePicker1.setFormats(dateFormat);
    Jobs();
}

public void Jobs() {
    try {
        Connection c = DB.myConnection();
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM totjobno WHERE ID='todayjob' AND date=('" + lblDate.getText().trim() + "')");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String x = rs.getString("TotJobNo");
            lblCuJobNo.setText(x);
        }
        c.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void clearTable() {
}

private void pendingList2(String getDate) {
    try {
        Connection c = DB.myConnection();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        DefaultTableModel tm33 = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        tm33.setRowCount(0);
        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM newjobsheet WHERE date=('" + getDate + "') ORDER BY sqNumber ");
        while (r.next()) {
            Vector v = new Vector();
            v.addElement(r.getString("sqNumber"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("date"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("JobNumber"));
            v.addElement(r.getString("DecName"));
            tm33.addRow(v);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Press OK!!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void btnAllPendingActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    jXDatePicker1.setDate(null);
    try {
        DefaultTableModel tm33 = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        tm33.setRowCount(0);
        Connection c = DB.myConnection();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM newjobsheet ORDER BY sqNumber ");
        while (r.next()) {
            Vector v2 = new Vector();
            v2.addElement(r.getString("sqNumber"));
            v2.addElement(r.getString("date"));
            v2.addElement(r.getString("JobNumber"));
            v2.addElement(r.getString("DecName"));
            tm33.addRow(v2);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Press OK!!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: is this class saraentry.MainFace? which line is line 73? sorry but you'll have to share more code if you want people to help you. looking at the stack trace, I suspect the error is not coming from the code you have shown but from some table clearing logic that you have implemented.

Comment: ok. i will put the whole code...

Comment: Line 73 is private 'void pendingList2(String getDate)'

Comment: Still I cant find why the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check what is going on in:

classes.RowListener.displayRowValues(RowListener.java:40) at classes.RowListener.valueChanged(RowListener.java:32) at

They seem to be your own classes.

In particular if you select any row in the table before the setRowCount(0) is called there is possibility of a selection change event being generated with either first or last index as -1.

So you should probably add check on the value of index being valid before proceeding further.

If your run following code and select second row in the table you will see selection event being fired with -1 as first index. So you should guard against same in your RowListener.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.addColumn("A");
    model.addRow(new String[]{"A"});
    model.addRow(new String[]{"A"});

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(table);
    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {            
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getFirstIndex() + ":" + e.getLastIndex());                
        }
    });

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    model.setRowCount(0);
}
```

Comment: As I think The exception in coming from `tm33.setRowCount(0);
`

Comment: You can probably post the RowListener code as well for quicker analysis.

Comment: No. In first method it might delete a row in table. after that in second method only it again going to clear the rows.

Comment: If you post the code in RowListener may be something will be come obvious.

Comment: Still I cant find why the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

1) create DefaultTableModel before you opening a Connection, and code line `tm33.setRowCount(0);` should be called before Databases operations too

2) remove from try - catch block

```
- `DefaultTableModel tm33 = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();`

- `tm33.setRowCount(0);`
```

3) add finally block to the try - catch, then in the finally shopuld be closed

```
    Connection c = DB.myConnection();
    Statement s = c.createStatement();
```

if query to the Databases are on short and periodical bases, then isn't required to close the Connection too,